# Shortest Vector in a lattice on a Galois Field

Tags: finite-fields, vector-lattices

I am trying to solve the shortest vector problem, but on a galois field rather than the real numbers.

Say, for example, I am working in the field of integers modulo 7, $Z_7$.
If I have the following lattice basis (where each column is a basis element), $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 0\\\ 2 & 0 & -5\\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

I already have a working algorithm for enumerating every combination of these basis elements within a fundamental parallelepiped.

What differences should there be in my algorithm compared to if I was calculating the shortest vector over the real numbers?

I wonder:

1. Should the fundamental parallelepiped be different?
2. Should I be calculating the norm of every enumerated vector differently?

Comment: You need to define a metric before you can discuss *shortest*. The field $\Bbb{Z}_7$ has no natural concept of *larger than*. Nor *length of a vector*. There are alternatives like the Hamming metric or the Lee metric, but you have to pick one, and then can ask for ways of finding the shortest vector.

Comment: Here *a metric* is also a tool for defining the distance between any pair of vectors. In a vector space you can equally well define *a norm*, but you do need to be careful. Over $\Bbb{Z}_7$ the vectors $(6,6,6)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$ are the same vector, so your definition of the norma must give the same answer to the two inputs.

Comment: (cont'd) You can, of course, choose to represent the coordinates by integers in the range $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but then to define a distance between a pair of vectors your definition of a norm must satisfy $||\vec{x}||=||-\vec{x}||$. Otherwise the symmetry requirement of a metric is violated.